# Excel - find a value in column A that appears less than or equal to 4 times and print in column B

Tags: excel

I have a list of usernames sorted alphabetically in column A, with some appearing numerous times.
I want to prnt the username in column B if it appears less than or equal to 4 times.

Do I need an array to go through all the different username values in the column to find the ones that appear less than or equal to 4 times?

Comment: Do you want the list to include only unique names, or one for each time it appears?

Comment: Sorry yes only unique names. So I really just column B to be populated with each username if it appears less than or equal to 4 times in A

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim A As Range, B As Range, v As String, K As Long
    Set A = Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    Set B = Range("B:B")

    K = 1

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
    For Each aa In A
        v = aa.Value
            If v <> "" Then
                If .CountIf(A, v) <= 4 Then
                    If .CountIf(B, v) = 0 Then
                        Cells(K, "B").Value = v
                        K = K + 1

                    End If
                End If
            End If
    Next aa
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this is impressive or excessive.

Comment: @DavidAndreiNed  I am not sure either.

Answer (score 2):

Add a helper column and place the following formula in the second row:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)<=4,COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)=1),MAX($B$1:B1)+1,"")
```

And copy down:

[image]

At this point you can filter on the non Blank Cells and copy them to another range.

If you want to use a formula to get the list then Put this in another column row 2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(ROW(1:1),B:B,0)),"")
```

And copy down.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No need for helper columns or VBA, just a bit of finely-tuned IF functions :)

`=IF(COUNTIFS(BE:BE,BE2)<=4,IF(COUNTIFS($BE$1:BE2,BE2)=1,BE2,"0"),"0")`

^Here, BE is where all your data is, starting on Row 2

What it does:

1. If the Name appears 4 or fewer times,
2. If this is the first time the Name appears in the column
3. Print the Name
4. (Otherwise insert 0)

To remove the 0 values i.e empty rows:

1. Paste over the formula with the same column as values (this is so you can..)
2. .. `Replace All` (<kbd>Ctrl-H</kbd>) "0"s with nothing "" (so that you can..)
3. .. Select the blank rows using `Go To` (<kbd>Ctrl-G</kbd>) `> Special > Blanks`
4. Delete (Shift Cells Up)

You can also simply Filter out the Blank/0 values

Comment: thanks, I've improved the answer in case people don't want the blank spaces